# Check if object complies with definition in typescript

Tags: typescript

I've a data structure like this

```
"properties": {
    "email": {
        "type": "string",
        "validations": ["required", "email"]
    },
    "address": {
        "street": {
            "type": "string",
            "validations": ["required"]
        },
        "zip": {
            "type": "number",
            "validations": ["required", "min(5)", "max(5)"]
        }
    }
}
```

Then I iterate on it using Object.entries(...)
How can I check if the object is either of the first type or the second one (which is composite)?

I could check for property names, but i want some neat solution using typescript ... any ideas?

Comment: You want to check the structure at runtime?

Comment: Yes
like this
 `props.map((p: { string: [string, [string]] } | [string, any]) => {
      let isProp = p is of type { string: [string, [string]] } ---> that what I think of
      if (isProp) {
       ....
      }
      else {
        console.log(p);
      }
    });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Runtime checking is not something that Typescript can help you with, Typescript types are pretty much gone at runtime. What Typescript can help you with is compile time checking. A custom type guard would be helpful to help you check and then have the variable typed correctly:

```
type Validation = { type: string, validations: string[] }
type ValidationContainer = { [name: string] : Validation | ValidationContainer };

// Type guard
function isValidation (v: Validation | ValidationContainer) : v is Validation {
    let vv = v as Validation;
    return  typeof vv.type === "string" && vv.validations instanceof Array;
}

function processTree(v:ValidationContainer, parent?:string) {
    for(let [key, value] of Object.entries(v)) {
        // value is  Validation | ValidationContainer
        if(isValidation(value)) {
            // value is Validation here after type guard
            console.log(value.type)
            console.log(value.validations)
        }else{
            // value is Validation here after type guard
            processTree(value, key)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: here is the final solution
https://gist.github.com/mustafamagdy/6a5098b5d8aaa4bcf267b0d7d39d514c